# PHP: displaying foreign key data by id variable data

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

include 'dbconnection.php';

$value = $_POST['value'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$value' INNER JOIN address ON users.address_id = address.id";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        ?>
        <a>Details for: <?php echo $row['Email'];?></a><br>
        <a>Address line 1: <?php echo $row['line1'];?></a><br>
        <a>Address line 2:<?php echo $row['line2'];?></a><br>
        <a>City: <?php echo $row['city'];?></a><br>
        <a>County: <?php echo $row['county'];?></a><br>
        <a>Postcode: <?php echo $row['postcode'];?></a><br>
        <a>Country: <?php echo $row['country'];?></a><br><br>


    <?php
    }
}

?>
```

I'm trying to allow an admin to view details of a user from the table users and then display the foreign key data in table address, all this should be done via an input to which would be stored into the $value variable. I can get every user in the table to show but not specifically one at a time. What am I missing?

Comment: Your mysql query has the wrong syntax. JOIN clauses are not allowed before the WHERE clause. The INNER JOIN isn't executed now.

Comment: @Gobbin Am I not correct in saying that the WHERE clause is in front of my JOIN clause? it's selecting it by value and then joining?

Comment: that's how mysql works. It needs a certain syntax or else it'll bug or not work at all. Same thing as when i want my SELECT clause after my WHERE clause. That is not the correct syntax and thus will my query not work.